# Service Setup not available in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning, servicecloud

Service Setup option is not visible in lightning experience. I have logged in via system admin profile and checked but the option isn’t coming.

Comment: It is available you might missing some permission. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_service_setup.htm&type=5

Comment: Is it service cloud you have licenses for?

Comment: @n34_panda The user I’m trying to test with is a service cloud user

Comment: Are you trying to add it to an App? Hmm, the user has service cloud user checked and the setting highlighted by rusher?

Comment: @n34_panda yeah according to salesforce documentation Customise Application System Permission on profile and service cloud user permission on the user would give access to service setup but nothing is working out

Comment: I am also having same issue. Service Setup is not available in Dev org. I have logged in as System Admin

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Dev org and Service Setup is available in the org. Looks like it's not available for old orgs.

When I edit a Console App in newly created org, I can see Setup Experience setting under App options. This setting is also missing in old org.